# accessing Rails Console after deploy to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, rails-console

I´m having trouble to access the rails console in production.

I used `Capistrano`to deploy the app to a VPS

If I cd to `deploy@myapp:~/myapp/current$`and run `bundle exec rails c`there I always get the option list for creating new rails project, like `rails new`

I've also tried `bundle exec rails console --production`and `rails console`etc all with the same outcome.

the thing is I must be able to access the console because I have to create an admin user for `active admin`

might be worth adding that I'm using Passenger/Capistrano and Nginx on Ubuntu 16

Does anyone know what is going on here? Am I doing something wrong?

***EDIT**

After running `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c` I get this message

```
 Looks like your app's ./bin/rails is a stub that was generated by Bundler.

 In Rails 4, your app's bin/ directory contains executables that are  versioned
 like any other source code, rather than stubs that are generated on demand.

  Here's how to upgrade:

  bundle config --delete bin    # Turn off Bundler's stub generator
   rake rails:update:bin         # Use the new Rails 4 executables
  git add bin                   # Add bin/ to source control

   You may need to remove bin/ from your .gitignore as well.

  When you install a gem whose executable you want to use in your app,
  generate it and add it to source control:

  bundle binstubs some-gem-name
  git add bin/new-executable

  Loading production environment (Rails 4.2.5)
  irb(main):001:0>
```

Comment: do you have the `~/myapp/current/bin` folder and does it contain `rails` ?

Comment: Yes it's in there, it seems to be empty though.... at least if I `ls`into it

Comment: yes, it should have the executable files. Check your Github repo, whether it has all the executable files with `bin` or not.

Comment: I checked, it is full of files in the Github repo

Comment: check `deploy.rb`, remove `bin` from `set :linked_dirs` and deploy once again, you should now expect to get all the executable files in your production.

Comment: I did that, Im deploying again now, crossing my fingers :)

Comment: Check the above comment, let me know if it works!

Comment: No it´s not working, I still get the same options list for rails, but the `bin`is now full of files...

Comment: `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c` - which error it is showing ?

Comment: I put it in Edit to the question please see it there

Comment: So, it opened your console as I see `Loading production environment (Rails 4.2.5)
  irb(main):001:0>`  , right ?

Comment: Yep, it did, is this the way to do this then?

Comment: Yes, this is the way! I am extending this as an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are missing executable files of `bin` folder in **Production** after Capistrano deployment.

You need to remove `bin` from `set :linked_dirs` from your Capistrano `deploy.rb` in order to avoid symlinking it.

You can again try `cap production deploy`, it would take all the executable files from `bin` to Production.

Now, you can access the rails console using:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helps me alot

Comment: `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c` was all I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Capistrano 3, you can include the rails:console option which will allow you to do this from your local machine to gain access to the console on the remote host:

`bundle exec cap production rails:console`

https://rubygems.org/gems/capistrano-rails-console

Comment: If I use the `capistrano-rails-console' gem and `cd` into    `deploy@myapp:~/myapp/current$` I get this error `(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- capistrano/rbenv
/home/deploy/hlinreykdal/releases/20160929002954/Capfile:25:in 'require'
/home/deploy/hlinreykdal/releases/20160929002954/Capfile:25:in '<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)`

Comment: Are you missing dependencies for it?
Are you using rbenv?

I would have to see your gemfile and capfile to know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

The Rails project is deployed in `/deploy/your_project_name/current` on the server by default. So, you can access it via SSH or ... and run `bundle exec rails c` to access the Rails console. It works for me!

Comment: This works, but only if you add `-e development` or `-e production` or whatever to specify the correct environment. `bundle exec rails c -e production`

Answer (score -1):

check if rvm and regarding gemset is suitable for the app

```
rvm gemset list 
rvm list
```

and then do

```
bin/rails rails c -e production
```